# How is clang able to steer C/C++ code optimization?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang, llvm

I was told that clang is a driver that works like gcc to do preprocessing, compilation and linkage work. During the compilation and linkage, as far as I know, it's actually llvm that does the optimization (`"-O1", "-O2", "-O3", "-Os", "-flto"`).

But I just cannot understand ***how* llvm is involved**.

It seems that compiling source code doesn't even need a static library such as `libLLVMCore.a`, instead for debian clang packages depends on another package called `libllvm-3.4`(clang version is 3.4), which contains `libLLVM-3.4.so(.1)`, does clang use this shared library for optimization?

I've checked clang source code for a while and found that `include/clang/Driver/Options.td` contains the related options, but unfortunately I failed to find the source files that *include* that file, so I'm still not aware of the mechanism.

I hope someone might give me some hints.

Comment: This may be yet another XY problem. What problem do you intend to solve if you get an answer to this question?

Comment: @MSalters I simply would like to know how clang can drive llvm to do the optimization work. I'm working on a project that *seems* requiring both clang sanitizer and llvm IR pass analysis, so I would like to know the details about how clang works. Basically we would like to implement a (much lightweight) driver that works like clang but targets on end-to-end code vulnerability checking.

Comment: Right, I was already feeling like there was a real problem somewhere. Wouldn't you be better off writing a target language description for LLVM and compiling to that? The LLVM compiler isn't restricted to targetting x86 or ARM, it's extendable. With a suitable target language defined, your vulnerabilities would stand out in the final output.

Comment: @MSalters i think writing a frontend for a target language is still difficult for me and we're currently only interested in c/c++ code with x86(32/64) as the architecture. So I hope there is a detailed  answer about the *driver interface* for llvm transformation and analysis pass.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? http://llvm.org/docs/index.html, http://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html, http://www.aosabook.org/en/llvm.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

<sub>*(TL;DontWannaRead - skip to the end of this answer)*</sub>

To answer your question properly you first need to understand the difference between a compiler's [front-end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Front_end) and [back-end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Back_end) (especially the first one).

Clang is a compiler **front-end** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) for C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ languages.

Clang's duty is the following:

[image]

i.e. translating from C++ source code (or C, or Objective C, etc..) to [LLVM IR](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html), a textual lower-level representation of what should that code do. In order to do this Clang employs a number of sub-modules whose descriptions you could find in any decent compiler construction book: lexer, parser + a semantic analyzer (Sema), etc..

[LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) is a set of libraries whose primary task is the following: suppose we have the LLVM IR representation of the following C++ function

```
int double_this_number(int num) {
    int result = 0;
    result = num;
    result = result * 2;
    return result;
}
```

the core of the LLVM passes should **optimize** LLVM IR code:

[image]

What to do with the optimized LLVM IR code is entirely up to you: you can translate it to x86_64 executable code or modify it and then spit it out as ARM executable code or GPU executable code. It depends on the goal of your project.

The term "back-end" is often confusing since there are many papers that would define the LLVM libraries a "middle end" in a compiler chain and define the "back end" as the final module which does the code generation (LLVM IR to executable code or something else which no longer needs processing by the compiler). Other sources refer to LLVM as a back end to Clang. Either way, their role is clear and they offer a powerful mechanism: whatever the language you're targeting (C++, C, Objective C, Python, etc..) if you have a front-end which translates it to LLVM IR, you can use the same set of LLVM libraries to optimize it and, as long as you have a back-end for your target architecture, you can generate optimized executable code.

Recalling that LLVM is a set of libraries (not just optimization passes but also [data structures](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#picking-the-right-data-structure-for-a-task), utility modules, diagnostic modules, etc..), Clang also leverages *many* LLVM libraries during its *front-ending* process. You can't really tear *every* LLVM module away from Clang since the latter is built on the former set.

As for the reason why Clang is said to be a "compilation driver": Clang manages interpreting the command line parameters (descriptions and many declarations are [TableGen](http://llvm.org/docs/TableGen/)'d and they might require a bit more than a simple grep to swim through the sources), decides which `Jobs` and phases are to be executed, set up the `CodeGenOptions` according to the desired/possible optimization and transformation levels and invokes the appropriate modules (`clangCodeGen` in `BackendUtil.cpp` is the one that populates a module pass manager with the optimizations to apply) and tools (e.g. the Windows `ld` linker). It steers the compilation process from the very beginning to the end.

Finally I would suggest reading Clang and LLVM documentation, they're pretty explicative and most of your questions should look for an answer there in the first place.

Comment: I guess my question is somewhat ambiguous, but you give such a *great* answer to tell me how to go deep into the IR generation, especially for the last three paragraphs; thank you so much!

Comment: btw, can you tell what's the tool to generate the picture?

Comment: @HongxuChen I used Publisher

Answer (score 10):

It's not exactly like GCC, so don't spend too much time trying to match the two precisely.

The LLVM compiler is a compiler for one specific language, LLVM. What Clang does is compile C++ code to LLVM, without optimizations. Clang can then invoke the LLVM compiler to compile that LLVM code to optimized assembly.

Comment: I know they are not exactly the same, but I hope to get *more details*  about *how* clang invoke llvm compiler to do the optimization work.